# Uninstalling a feature with p2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4, p2

I*m trying to uninstall a feature from eclipse using p2 operations.

What I'm doing to achieve this:

```
OperationFactory of = new OperationFactory();
ProfileChangeOperation operation;
//toInstall = List<IVersionedId> only containing the feature
operation = of.createUninstallOperation(toInstall, repos, monitor);
```

After that, I'm running the operation.

The feature will be successfully uninstalled, but **plugins that are part of this feature, which are no dependencies of other features / plugins will remain installed.** This is unwanted behaviour.

I already tried to add

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/gcOnStartup=true
```

to my product properties.

I also tried to run

```
eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application -profile DefaultProfile
```

No effect.

I added

```
-profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true
```

to my program arguments. No effect.

Additionally I tried to implement GC programatically, which had no effect either.

Any idea how to fix this? P2 installs features including all dependant plugins. I expected it to behave the same on uninstall operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only occured if buildig with tycho. I managed to fix this by adding `org.eclipse.update.configurator` with start level 4 and Auto-Start = false to my product start levels.

Additionaly, I added `org.eclipse.update.reconcile` with the value false to the properties in my product configuration.

By using this special combination of settings, uninstalled plugins won't show up  anymore.